# Biblatex dashed entries with "sortname" and "shortauthor"

Tags: biblatex

In a bibliography with dashed entries, I'd prefer variants like `J. Lennon` and `John Lennon` to behave as the same name. In other words, the latter entry should be dashed. I've tried to enforce this by setting `SHORTAUTHOR = "John Lennon", SORTNAME = "John Lennon"` in the entry for `J. Lennon`, but it has no effect.

How can I get a dashed entry for the `lennon1971` entry in the following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, dashed = true, sorting = nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J. Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SHORTAUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a `biber` sourcemap to change all Lennon names to something the same and then dashes would work. This way you don't have to change the source `.bib`.

Comment: @PLK Sounds reasonable. I'll see if I can manage on my own before I'll ask you to show me how ``:)``

Comment: @PLK How about this: If there's something specified in the ``shortauthor`` field, use that to replace whatever is in ``author``?

Comment: Just curious but why should the entry match the bibliographic source if there is no doubt that 'A. Smith' is, in fact, the same person as 'Anna Smith'? (I ask partly because my entries definitely do not obey this rule.)

Comment: @cfr As a general rule, the bibliographic information given in your paper should reflect the information in your source. Many style sheets I have followed explicitly require the names to be written as they are written in the source. Do you also spell out middle initials? And what about cases where people publish under a different name than their legal name (this is pretty common in academia, especially for women who marry and take their husband's name)? Would you erase the non-legal part and add their legal name?

Comment: @Sverre If that's so, you ought not treat different forms of the same name in the way you wish to. That is, your bibliography will present 2 papers by, say 'Jones, Dai' although one of them is by 'Jones, D.' or vice-versa. I generally include more, rather than less, information in the name. But I try to format names in the bibliography according to the form which the person uses. So bell hooks is 'hooks, bell'. That it is not her legal name is neither here nor there. That is the name she chooses. (Cases in which somebody has changed name I treat specially. I have 2 names in the database.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, I think I have reached the same conclusion, that I shouldn't dash an entry if the non-dashed entry has information that differs from the dashed entry.

Comment: I'm just roaming the unanswered questions a bit and happened upon this again. Do you have any idea what to do with it? Do you want an answer? Is the question just obsolete after the discussion in the comments?

Comment: @moewe I don't have a solution. What I have done is to either (1) keep what my MWE above is giving me, or (2) create a new `.bib` file for the article I'm writing and put the same name in the `author` field.  Option (2) is not exactly ideal, so if you have a solution to my original question, I think it would be good for me and whoever else has this problem if you posted an answer (if you have one?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by PLK in the comments, you can use a sourcemap to replace some forms of the name for another standardized one, without having to change your bib file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, dashed = true, sorting = nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J. Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author,
            match={J. Lennon},
            replace={John Lennon}]
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]